# Random integer with conditions

Tags: php, random

I have a PHP script where I have an array of integers, let's say `$forbidden`.

I want to get a random integer from 1 to 400 that is not in `$forbidden`.

Of course, I don't want any loop which breaks when rand gives a working result. I'd like something more effective.

How do you do this ?

Comment: Why is looping not effective?

Comment: @MichaelRobinson: It's not effective because $forbidden can be very large.

Paul: I've thought of getting all the integers possible in an array and then get a sample from it but I was wondering if there's something nicer in the language

Comment: @MichaelRobinson: Looping is ineffective because in theory you may hit forbidden numbers 1000000 times in a row (though if that happens you probably should go and fill in some lottery), but yeah.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Place all forbidden numbers in an array, and use `array_diff` from `range(1,400)`. You'll get an array of allowed numbers, pick a random one with `array_rand()`.

```
<?php

$forbidden = array(2, 3, 6, 8);
$complete = range(1,10);
$allowed = array_diff($complete, $forbidden);

echo $allowed[array_rand($allowed)];
```

This way you're removing the excluded numbers from the selection set, and nullifying the need for a loop :)

Comment: I didn't know array_diff, was looking for it for a while ! Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Produce an array of the allowed numbers. Find out the number in this array. Select one of those randomly.